# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'd72709_nimrod.api2_acl_attribute' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, magento

I was perfectly able to add attributes to my magento e-commerce system.

I've tried to add one more attribute and it suddenly failed and keeps failing with this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'd72709_nimrod.api2_acl_attribute' doesn't exist

I desperately need help while I'm not a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody runs into this issue, create the table with this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `api2_acl_attribute` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `user_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Type of user',
  `resource_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Resource ID',
  `operation` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Operation',
  `allowed_attributes` text COMMENT 'Allowed attributes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_API2_ACL_ATTRIBUTE_USER_TYPE_RESOURCE_ID_OPERATION` (`user_type`,`resource_id`,`operation`),
  KEY `IDX_API2_ACL_ATTRIBUTE_USER_TYPE` (`user_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Api2 Filter ACL Attributes' AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `api2_acl_attribute`
--

INSERT INTO `api2_acl_attribute` (`entity_id`, `user_type`, `resource_id`, `operation`, `allowed_attributes`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', 'all', '', NULL);
```

and you may need this also:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `api2_acl_role` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Created At',
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Updated At',
  `role_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of role',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_API2_ACL_ROLE_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
  KEY `IDX_API2_ACL_ROLE_UPDATED_AT` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Api2 Global ACL Roles' AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `api2_acl_role`
--

INSERT INTO `api2_acl_role` (`entity_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `role_name`) VALUES
(1, '2014-09-22 14:42:06', NULL, 'Guest'),
(2, '2014-09-22 14:42:06', NULL, 'Customer'),
(3, '2015-03-19 12:13:02', NULL, 'Admin');
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `api2_acl_rule` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Role ID',
  `resource_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Resource ID',
  `privilege` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ACL Privilege',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_API2_ACL_RULE_ROLE_ID_RESOURCE_ID_PRIVILEGE` (`role_id`,`resource_id`,`privilege`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Api2 Global ACL Rules' AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `api2_acl_rule`
--

INSERT INTO `api2_acl_rule` (`entity_id`, `role_id`, `resource_id`, `privilege`) VALUES
(1, 3, 'all', NULL);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `api2_acl_user` (
  `admin_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Admin ID',
  `role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Role ID',
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_API2_ACL_USER_ADMIN_ID` (`admin_id`),
  KEY `FK_API2_ACL_USER_ROLE_ID_API2_ACL_ROLE_ENTITY_ID` (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Api2 Global ACL Users';

--
-- Dumping data for table `api2_acl_user`
--

INSERT INTO `api2_acl_user` (`admin_id`, `role_id`) VALUES
(5, 3);

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `api2_acl_rule`
--
ALTER TABLE `api2_acl_rule`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_API2_ACL_RULE_ROLE_ID_API2_ACL_ROLE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `api2_acl_role` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `api2_acl_user`
--
ALTER TABLE `api2_acl_user`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_API2_ACL_USER_ADMIN_ID_ADMIN_USER_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`admin_id`) REFERENCES `admin_user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_API2_ACL_USER_ROLE_ID_API2_ACL_ROLE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `api2_acl_role` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```